# Client License Transition to Solo/Pro

Tags: craft-pro, license, pricing

I have a Craft site with a Client license. After the recent license transition to Solo/Pro, a red banner appears along the top that reads "You’re running Craft Client with a Craft Pro license. [Resolve]." Hitting "resolve" displays the following:
[image: Craft Solo - Pro Screen]

So, if I reinstall as pro, is that a new $299 charge (plus the annual $59)? Will "reinstalling" result in system downtime and/or data loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard -- this was directly addressed by the 2.6.3015 update that was just released. The message no longer appears.